# Releasing custom RPC implementation on only a single testnet runtime

Tags: custom-rpc

We have multiple testnet runtimes configured for the node. A new pallet I'm building is only available for testing in one testnet. There is also a new custom RPC I have written to call into the new pallet. How do I prevent errors caused by some of the runtimes not implementing the RPC interface because they don't have the new pallet included/configured when building the node?

I wonder if cargo features might help here, but not sure how to use it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just define some empty/dummy impl of the rpc interface, e.g beefy pallet is enabled in rococo but not yet in [polkadot](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/b216f1f79809273e9f525ce5791e1af0e3aef36b/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L1911-L1916)

or you can define particular [rpc collections](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/b216f1f79809273e9f525ce5791e1af0e3aef36b/node/client/src/lib.rs#L122-L136) for each runtime

Comment: I guess I will go with the dummy impl approach for now. Thanks. But can you elaborate on how rpc collections approach would solve the problem?

Comment: just try dummy impl, with rpc collections approach much more effort